# С прописной или строчной буквы пишутся отфамильные термины?

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия

С прописной или строчной буквы пишутся отфамильные  термины (например, анатомические термины "(с)ильвиев водопровод", "(в)иллизиев круг")?

Answer (score 2):

1) Согласно общим правилам орфографии такие названия пишутся **со строчной буквы.**

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=16#pp16

2) Пример написания со строчной буквы (справочник по неврологии)

За счет **сильвиева водопровода** происходит циркуляция спинно-мозговой жидкости
Источник: http://neurodoc.ru/anatomy/silviev-vodoprovod.html

3) Однако в  литературе на медицинскую тему  встречается написание с **прописной буквы**, например:

Ранее в семнадцатом веке был известный ученый по имени Франциск Сильвий. Он как раз и занимался исследованиями мозга. Именно ему принадлежат заслуги по открытию и описанию такого отдела, как **Сильвиев водопровод**, названного впоследствии в его честь.
Источник: https://amhealh.ru/vodoprovod-mozga.html

Такие написания, вероятно, являются **традиционными** и могут считаться допустимыми, если учесть что  **в специальной литературе** возможно  употребление прописных букв в названиях **по  особым правилам**.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, ответ содержится в [§ 12. Прилагательные и наречия, образованные от индивидуальных названий](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=16#pp16)

> Имена прилагательные, обозначающие индивидуальную принадлежность, если они образованы от имен лиц, кличек животных, названий мифологических существ с помощью суффикса -ов (-ев) или -ин-, пишутся с прописной буквы: Марксов «Капитал», Гегелева «Логика», Вандейкова мадонна, Зевсов гнев, Одиссеевы странствия; Надина кукла, Муркины котята.
>
> **Однако во фразеологических оборотах и научных терминах подобные прилагательные пишутся со строчной буквы:** ариаднина нить, ахиллесова пята, геркулесовы столбы, прокрустово ложе, эзопов язык; архимедов рычаг, базедова болезнь, рентгеновские лучи.

Дополнение. Я искал с помощю Google среди книг (Books). В большинстве книг *сильвиев водопровод* и *виллизиев круг* пишутся со строчной, но не во всех. Как объяснить наличие варианта с прописной, я не знаю.

Comment: *Как объяснить наличие варианта с прописной, я не знаю.* - только ошибочным применением общего правила там, где это неправомерно.

Answer (score 0):

Со строчной. И дело не только в традиции, суть в том, что данные термины исходно не имели  или утратили связь тем в честь кого они названы. За ученым или исследователем остается обычно только приоритет открытия (да и то не всегда, бывает и просто случайные названия - броуновское движение, кесарево сечение и даже докторская колбаса, предположительно обязанная своему названию некому Дохторову, сотруднику микояновского комбината). Таким образом термины теряют семантику *притяжательности* и сближаются с фразеологизмами.

Остальное - см. у М_Г.